# How can I just remove the KEY key in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

**Good Friday night!**

I solve one problem that accommodates the full work of the fund's attendance statistics panel and I'll show you the official information of my MySQL-table of requests to the site:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `statistic` (
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `ip` text NOT NULL,
 `city` text NOT NULL,
 `region` longtext NOT NULL,
 `country` longtext NOT NULL,
 `ua` text NOT NULL,
 `source` text NOT NULL,
 `page` text NOT NULL,
 `month` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
 `week` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `resource` text NOT NULL,
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12442 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I'm currently testing a new version of the "Regions" tab of the statistics bar itself.
And I want to see in the newest version implemented by me on PHP and Yii1 the system of showing a table of unique cities depending on the chosen country and region and not able to see, having received this error:

**Undefined index: city**

And I applied the correct working PHP code in the tab template:

```php
<?php
  else if (isset($_GET['country']) && isset($_GET['region'])) {
                $c = trim($_GET['country']);
                $r = trim($_GET['region']);
                $static=Yii::app()->db->CreateCommand();
                $static->selectDistinct("city");
                $static->from("statistic");
                $static->where(array("and","resource='Добрые-Взрослые'","country='". $c ."'","region='". $r ."'"));
                $regions=$static->queryAll();

                foreach ($regions as $list) {

                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td><a href='/static/?static_page=regions&country=". $c ."&region=". $r ."&city=". $list['city'] ."'><img src='data:image/png;base64,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' /></a></td>";
                   echo "<td>". $list['city'] ."</td>";
                   $static=Yii::app()->db->CreateCommand('SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ip) FROM statistic WHERE resource="Добрые-Взрослые" AND city="'. $list['city'] .'" AND region="'. $r .'" AND country="'. $c .'"');
                   $count=$static->queryScalar();
                   echo "<td>". $count ."</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
                }
              }
?>
```

> The algorithm itself is responsible for showing unique cities depending on the country and region selected by HTTP GET requests

1. Then I tried to enter the command in MySQL Terminal:

```sql
SHOW CREATE TABLE statistic;
```

2.Checked that the other tables do not have simple keys and it turned out to have prevented the full operation of the new version of the tab here is this passage:

```sql
KEY `date` (`date`);
```

3.By posting on the Internet how to remove the key in the column using **DROP KEY**, I tried some options to use **DROP KEY**, in a column where it needs a problem, and MySQL considered options acceptable syntax errors.

> Guys, please tell me how to properly remove with DROP the type of KEY key used in the column "city" to avoid an unacceptable index error?

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

[My question source](https://toster.ru/q/676479)

[My question translated in English on Bing Translate and been editing!](https://www.bing.com/translator)

Answer (score -1):

`$list` is object so you should use this code:

```
$list->city
```